# Spring autowiring parameter by name

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans with the type `InterfaceA`.
I was trying to inject the bean into an argument of a `@Bean` method using `@Qualifier` to autowire by name.
I was surprising that Spring can't resolve the proper bean unless your parameter name is matching the bean name.

I was trying:

```
@Component
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
}

@Component
public class ClassB implements InterfaceA {
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("classA")
    public SomeOtherClass someOtherClass(InterfaceA object) {...}
}
```

But got the `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`.
However if I use parameter name matching the component name it works fine.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SomeOtherClass someOtherClass(InterfaceA classA) {...}
}
```

Could someone explain why I can't use autowiring by name with `@Resource` or `@Qualifier` here?

Comment: Please add the complete Stacktrace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `@Qualifier` annotation to the parameter not to the method:

```
public SomeOtherClass someOtherClass(@Qualifier("classA") InterfaceA object) {...}
```